# Is it possible to include external javascript code in a coucdhb list function?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

...not more to add apart the title:

I have a list functions which formats the result of a view according to some values contained in an array

var array=[val1, val2, val3...]

As this array is also used in my javascript client-side functions, and grabbed from a globvar.js file on the server, is it possible to include it in a list functions?

How?

Should I execute an ajax request?

thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in a CommonJS module: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules

You can't do ajax requests within CouchDB.

EDIT: latest documentation is at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/query-server/javascript.html#require

Comment: how if the database I used is hosted remotely (e.g. cloudant.com)?

Comment: I've never used Cloudant, however if it works on CouchDB it should work on Cloudant.